# How to calculate the number of combinations of different integers under these conditions?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, combinations

Given a bound, say $1$ - $N$, and $n$ different integers within this bound such that the summation of these $n$ integers is $m$. What is the number of possible combinations of $n$ different integers within the bound $1$ - $N$, whose summation $\geq m$? How to calculate it? I have tried recursion, but it began to become slow when $n$ is larger than $10$.

Comment: It is a very non-trivial task. For starters, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)